# Redirect few pages to new pages on new domain and the rest to the mainpage with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to setup a redirection with .htaccess file.

So far I have this:

```
Redirect 301 /temat-konfiguracja-internetu-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/konfiguracja-internetu-w-a2mobile-22500
Redirect 301 /temat-konfiguracja-mms-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/konfiguracja-mms-w-a2mobile-22499
Redirect 301 /temat-jak-sprawdzic-stan-konta-w-a2mobile-oraz-inne-kody-ussd-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/jak-sprawdzic-stan-konta-w-a2mobile-oraz-inne-kody-ussd-w-a2mobile-1812
Redirect 301 /temat-jak-sprawdzic-swoj-numer-telefonu-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/jak-sprawdzic-swoj-numer-telefonu-w-a2mobile-22497
Redirect 301 /temat-konfiguracja-apn-internetu-i-mms-samsung-galaxy-s4 https://infomobile.pl/konfiguracja-apn-internetu-i-mms-samsung-galaxy-s4-11561
Redirect 301 /forum-internet-mobilny-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/internet-mobilny-w-a2mobile-31
Redirect 301 /temat-ostrzegam-roaming-nie-dziala-w-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/ostrzegam-roaming-nie-dziala-w-a2mobile-22494
Redirect 301 /temat-stan-konta-a2mobile https://infomobile.pl/stan-konta-a2mobile-22498
Redirect 301 /temat-rozwiązany-problem-z-konfiguracja-apn-na-urzadzeniu-meizu-m2-mini https://infomobile.pl/rozwiazany-problem-z-konfiguracja-apn-na-urzadzeniu-meizu-m2-mini-1817
Redirect 301 /temat-logowanie https://infomobile.pl/logowanie-761
Redirect 301 /mapa-index.xml https://infomobile.pl/sitemap/sitemap.xml
```

But... for all the other pages I want to setup a whole domain redirection (so for all the pages that are not on the list I want to point aero2forum.pl to infomobile.pl). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure, just implement a `RedirectRule` as a "catch all" below those specifalized rules. You will find hundreds of examples for redirection rules here on SO and it definitely does make sense to take a look into the documentation of the apache rewrite module: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

To redirect everything else to the root of the target domain you will need to add a (mod_alias) `RedirectMatch` directive *after* your existing (mod_alias) `Redirect` directives.

For example:

```
:

# Redirect everything else to the target domain's homepage
RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://example.target/
```

However, it should be noted, that from a search engine perspective, multiple redirects to the homepage will likely be seen as a soft-404. (And reported as such in Google Search Console.)

This does assume that the source and target domains point to different server's. Otherwise, this will naturally result in a redirect loop. You could avoid the redirect-loop by not redirecting the homepage, eg. `^/.`. However, if both domains point to the same server then you will need to convert everything to use mod_rewrite instead and explicitly check the requested hostname.

---

*Aside:* You cannot use a (mod_rewrite) `RewriteRule` here since it will take priority over the existing `Redirect` directives (regardless of the order) and end up redirecting *everything* to the homepage of the target domain.